# Angular sort object by property

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need help to solve a problem, I try to sort a object by properties, but I have the problem bellow, if some one can help me

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

[image: Screenshot 3]

Comment: That's [Angular](https://angular.io/), not [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/)

Comment: Can you edit the post please so it is readable?

Comment: This is an English language forum, so if you'd like to get help it will improve your chances if the error messages linked in your post are also in English.

Comment: ok next time I will be carefull

Comment: It a lot better you copy and paste the code here instead of screen shots.

Answer (score 1):

I don't speak french, but I think it might be warning you that nameCity might be undefined, since on the type definition nameCity is optional: `nameCity?:string`. You could try:

```
a.nameCity?.localeCompare(b.nameCity)
```

**EDIT:**

in case the nameCity values can actually be undefined, the sort would have to look something like this:

```
array.sort((a,b)=>{
  if(a.nameCity){
    return a.nameCity.localeCompare(b.nameCity);
  }
  return 1; // or -1 depending  if you want the undefined to go first or last
})
```

Comment: This is likely the correct assumption considering the provided type. Your answer might not be correct however as I believe `.sort()` requires a numerical return value.

Comment: localeCompare does return a number https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

Comment: but it won't if `nameCity` is undefined, it will return undefined, also your trailing `?` isn't valid

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, I am guessing this is a typing error, and nameCity is not actually optional, but I will update the answer.

Comment: @LuizAvila thank you for the suggestion, I try the suggestion but I have another error like on the line `return a.nameCity.localeCompare(b.nameCity?);` it tell me that **waiting for expression**

Comment: My bad you don't need the last ?